# Python glob fails?

Tags: python, wildcard, glob

I want to glob several directories, each containing a file named GDS_XYZ/GDS_XYZ.summary.txt.
XYZ changes from folder to folder, so I do

```
glob.glob('GDS_*/GDS*.summary.txt')
```

However, the result is `['GDS_0744-2358/GDS*.summary.txt']` instead of `['GDS_0744-2358/GDS_0744-2358.summary.txt']`

Can anyone tell my why that is and what I can do about it? As far as I can see, glob takes multiple wildcards...
Thanks!

Comment: The result should be a list and you're missing a parenthesis.  Unfortunately, this one is going to be pretty hard to solve unless you give us something that we can reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

People hate me when i bring other solutions in to the table.
But consider:

```
import os
for root, folders, files in os.walk('./'):
    if os.path.basename(root)[:4] == 'GDS_':
        print('Checking: ' + root)
        for f_name in files:
              if f_name[:3] == 'GDS':
                  print('\t' + f_name)
```

It will recursivly check a folder structure under `./` and see if the folder it's standing in is named `GDS_*` and if so, check all the files in it for `GDS*`.
Then it will traverse the next folder and so on.

Comment: I was always the ugly kid on the block, but i fixed a lot of problems when hiding out in a shed :) You're welcome and as a last resort it will do :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because I do lots of things in both bash and python, but I prefer to use the shell's glob function via the sh module:

```
import sh
sh.glob('what*ever/some*thing')
```

If there are any differences with python and bash glob functionality I don't need to know because I just use the shell.

Comment: `sh.glob` is just a *really thin* wrapper around `glob.glob` (`def glob(s):return glob.glob(s) or s`).  This won't make much difference for OP I don't think.

Comment: @mgilson - heh. thanks. from the comment here https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L190 it looks like they do that in case there is no match and the glob doesn't expand.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Formic](http://www.aviser.asia/formic) (disclosure: I am the author). Formic does exactly what you expect for globs that include one (or more) directories:

```
import formic
fileset = formic.FileSet(include="GDS_*/GDS*.summary.txt")

for file_name in fileset:
    # Do something with file_name
```

Formic starts its search the the current working directory by default. You can also use the named argument `directory` to start elsewhere:

```
fileset = formic.FileSet(include="GDS_*/GDS*.summary.txt", directory="/some/where/else")
```

Hope this works for you